# * Use a for-loop to add all the odd values in the range `28` to `47` to a * string with each number separated by a comma `,`

Tags: javascript

Use a for-loop to add all the odd values in the range `28` to `47` to a
string with each number separated by a comma `,`.

The result should not end with a comma. You should neither have a space after the comma.

Answer with the resulting string.

```
var sum;
 for (var i = 28; i <= 47; i +=2){
    sum += i + ", ";
}
```

Fail You said:
"28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, " (string)

Hint: the correct output is:
"29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47" (string)

How to dd all the odd values in the range `28` to `47?
Can someone help me out?

Comment: You start with an even number. Even numbers are never odd. Also note that you have an additional trailing comma, and it explicitly states no spaces after the commas.

Comment: this sounds like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start from `29` instead of `28`

```js
var sum = "";
for (var i = 29; i <= 47; i +=2){
    sum += i + ",";
}
console.log(sum)
```

A fancy way to do the same thing

```js
var sum = "";
for (var i = 29; i <= 47; i +=2){
    sum += i + ",";
}
sum = sum.slice(0,-1)
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: This adds an additional trailing comma. IMO just handing out the answer isn't the most educational approach, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton its fixed using slice

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sum = "";
for (var i = 29; i <= 46; i +=2){
    sum += i + ",";
}
sum =sum+47;
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

... and yet another approach: ;-)

```js
for (var arr=[], i=47; i>28; i-=2) arr.push(i);

console.log(arr.reverse().join(','))
```